# Merge results of query

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a query that outputs its values as json in the following format:

```
[
    {
        "name":"Bob",
        "date":"2016-02-05 00:00:00",
        "value":34
    },
    {
        "name":"John",
        "date":"2016-02-05 00:00:00",
        "value":5
    },
    {
        "name":"Bob",
        "date":"2016-02-05 00:00:00",
        "value":3
    },
    {
        "name":"Sarah",
        "date":"2016-02-05 00:00:00",
        "value":56
    }

    ...
]
```

I need to put this data into the form:

```
[
    {
        "name":"Bob",
        "data": [
            [2016-02-05 00:00:00, 34],
            [2016-02-05 00:00:00, 3]
        ]
    },
    {
        "name":"John",
        "data": [
            [2016-02-05 00:00:00, 5]
        ]
    },
    {
        "name":"Sarah",
        "data": [
            [2016-02-05 00:00:00, 56]
        ]
    }

    ...
]
```

Or in other words, I need to combine the results that share a `name` and put the data into an array `data`, where each array holds the `date` and `value`.

The original json data is held in a variable `$results`:

```
foreach ($results as $result)
{
    //
}
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
function process_results($results) {
   $out = [];

   foreach ($results as $result) {
      $name = $result['name'];
      if ( ! $out[$name]) {
         $out[$result['name']] = array( 'name' => $name, 'data' => array());
      }

      array_push($out[$name]['data'], array($result['date'], $result['value']));
   }

   return array_values($out);
}
```

This also seems to work

```
function process_results($results) {
   return array_values(array_reduce($results, function($acc, $result) {
      $name = $result['name'];
      if ( ! $acc[$name]) {
         $acc[$result['name']] = array( 'name' => $name, 'data' => array());
      }

      $acc[$name]['data'][] = array($result['date'], $result['value']);
      return $acc;
  }, []));
}
```